# Set data into ng-content

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a custom select element.

Component:

```
@Component(
    {
        selector   : 'plain-select-view',
        templateUrl: './plain-select.component.html',
        styleUrls  : ['./plain-select.component.scss']      
    }
)
export class PlainSelectComponent { ...
```

Part of template

```
<div class="dropdown-area" [@dropdownStatus]="dropdownStatus">
    <div class="dropdown-item font-regular-13"
         *ngFor="let item of dropdownValues"
         (click)="selectItem(item)"
         [class.selected]="isSelected(item)">
        <ng-content [item]="item"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

in other component:

```
<plain-select-view>
  <div class="some-class">{{item}}</div>
</plain-select-view>
```

Comment: Can you please add more code? How are these HTML parts related. What elements are components?

Comment: It's a part of component which is a custom dropdown select. I want to set dropdown item through ng-content and set data in it

Comment: Please add more code, that demonstrates how these things are related.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer now better?

Comment: It's better. What do you want to pass from where to where?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have a base component of custom dropdown. But how should look list I want pass outside this component